# Continuity of a piecewise map

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to check continuity of map $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to D^2$ (where $D^2$ is closed unit ball) given by:

$$x \to\begin{cases} 
      x & \|x\|\leq 1 \\
      \frac{x}{\|x\|} & \|x\|>1
      \end{cases}$$

My attempt:

I am wondering if it is enough to show that,  $ \lim_{||x||\to 1} f(x)=x $. That seems to be true intuitively. I need a rigorous proof.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: both pieces are continuous on their domains,  so you just need to show that they agree on the boundary,  via the pasting lemma. Will post details

Comment: @Alan, for pasting lemma we first need to partition our domain as a union of open sets or a union of closed sets, which I can not do here.

Comment: As you see in the answer below, you just extend the part on the outer part to include the boundary so they are both clsoed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pasting lemma is what you are looking for here.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma

Let $X$ be the closed unit ball and let $Y$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the open unit ball,  these are both closed spaces and their union is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.   So to use the pasting lemma, we just need $f$ to have unambiguous definitions on their boundary,  i.e. it wouldn't matter which formula you used.  Fortunately you have that here.   So we can say that $f$ restricted to $X$ is $f(x)=x$, continuous,  and $f$ restricted to $Y$ is $f(x)=\frac x {\|x\|}$,  continuous.   Note this only works because on the overlap the two definitions agree.    Then the pasting lemma gives us the function itself is continuous